# bash log in windows and run cmd command using .sh script?

Tags: linux, bash, window

Ip of my Windows machine is 172.16.22.53, and it installed cygwin.
I want write a bash script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sshpass -p 'myPassWord' ssh userNmae@172.16.22.53
#and some command to run cmd command in the Windows machine.
```

Is it possible?

That is my try(it log in the Windows machine,and go into cygwin command interface .But don't creat the Catalog(myth) in the Windows machine!):

```
#!/bin/bash 
sshpass -p 'myPassWord' ssh userNmae@myIp|mkdir myth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not very clear what isn't working for you.  If you just want to run a command remotely, `sshpass` can help you.

Maybe you just have the syntax a little bit wrong.  For example, the following command will login to a remote server, check the uptime and print the uname:

```
sshpass -p '<password>' ssh <username>@<myIp> "uptime;uname -a"
```

Note the quoting of the commands.

A better solution might be to use `ssh-keygen` to login securely without using a password.

This page was helpful: http://www.nextstep4it.com/categories/unix-command/sshpass/